# Setting DataContext on ViewModel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, viewmodel

The Page2.xaml uses SampleData, which works perfectly in the designer.
When I'm calling Page2.xaml from MainPage.xaml, and try to set loaded data for Page2.xaml

```
public Page2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!App.Page2VM.IsDataLoaded)
    {
        App.Page2VM.LoadData();
    }

    App app = (App)Application.Current;
    this.DataContext = App.Page2VM; <-- error here
}
```

I got an error. This code works for MainPage.xaml with MainVM. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the rest of your code, so it's difficult to get the right answer.

However, looking at your snippet, I found the following: you're initializing the app var after the code of loading the data. In my opinion, you should place the code App

app = (App)Application.Current; this.DataContext = App.Page2VM;

'before' the if snippet that loads the data.